# Is there a way to easily duplicate/clone an entry in EE3?

Tags: ee3, duplicate, mx-cloner

This is mainly for pages. My is reusing a lot of the same content on some pages and would like the ability to clone them to save time.

MX Cloner did this is EE2 and I guess I assumed it would be something built in to EE3.

Comment: Don't suppose you have found anything to help with this issue? Such a time waste.

Answer (score 1):

Max the developer has Mx Cloner for ee3 development in progress so its on the way no dates on that though 
http://status.eec.ms/

Answer (score 1):

I have found SimpleCloner for EE3. It is given more option than MX Cloner.

See github link : https://github.com/ThorntonStuart/SimpleCloner